# Emacs client can't find server in terminal

Tags: emacsclient, emacs-daemon

So, I'm trying to set up emacs as a server but I'm having trouble getting it to work from the terminal. If I run emacs --daemon on some terminal I can connect to it if I run the emacsclient from that same terminal, but if I open a new terminal the emacsclient will not find the server. Things seem to work well if I run emacsclient from the launcher.

I am running

```
emacsclient -a '' -t
```

The client says:

```
emacsclient: can't find socket; have you started the server?
To start the server in Emacs, type "M-x server-start".
```

Any ideas of what could be happening?

I am using ubuntu 17.04 with gnome/i3 if that matters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used to have the same issue until I did:

`alias e="emacsclient -t --socket-name=/tmp/emacs1000/server"`

And now I just use this `"e"` alias to start emacsclient.

I haven't seen the issue since.

Comment: This worked, how do I tell the server to start the /tmp/emacs1000/server ? (the first client is starting it for me)

Comment: Before running an emacsclient, I always first start the emacs server as `emacs --daemon` and it always starts listening on that `/tmp/emacs1000/server` socket automatically.  I'm sure there's a less hacky way to do this that doesn't involve hardcoding the `/tmp/emacs1000/server` location in the `e` alias, and would always work no matter where the socket is created by the server (and that is probably how emacsclient is intended to work when invoked without the `--socket-name` option), but doing it this simple hackish way always worked for me.

Comment: @MatíasGuzmánNaranjo Using command like `lsof -w -c emacs | grep 'server'` you'll know what the exact socket-name is, and if you are using emacs-28, you'll notice that the socket-name is not `/tmp/emacs1000/server` anymore, it is `/run/user/1000/emacs/server`

Comment: mine is under `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-server.so.0.1.0` is it normal?

Answer (score 9):

Make sure you are using the same version of `emacs` and `emacsclient`.

When my system emacsclient is used instead of my custom build emacs, I'm getting a similar error:

```
$ /usr/bin/emacsclient --version
emacsclient 22.1

$ /usr/bin/emacsclient .
/usr/bin/emacsclient: can't find socket; have you started the server?
To start the server in Emacs, type "M-x server-start".
```

With the correct version:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/emacsclient --version
emacsclient 26.0.50

$ /usr/local/bin/emacsclient .
Waiting for Emacs...
```

Comment: This solves my problem

Comment: Yes that solves mine too. I just recently upgrade my emacs version from 25 to 27, but the `emacsclient` link was pointing to the old version. So `sudo update-alternatives --config emacsclient` to update the links.

Answer (score 5):

For unfathomable reasons, this just happened to me on a FC28 upgrade of my laptop. Even stracing ddid not help. After perusing several links (this included), I came up by sticking these lines:

```
# bash syntax
# On laptop, emacscclient cannot find emacs socket any longer (after FC28)
export EMACS_SERVER_SOCKET=${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/emacs$(id -u)/server
alias emacsclient="/usr/bin/emacsclient -s $EMACS_SERVER_SOCKET"
```

Which does not hardcode the '1000' part (which just happpens to be the id of the first user created on this particular machine, duh), and accounts for TMPDIR. Exporting EMACS_SERVER_SOCKET is cute, but useless, as emacsclient does not allow that to be configured from an env var (unreasonably, IMHO).

If full control is preferred, one can put:

```
(setq server-socket-dir "~/.emacs.d/server-dir")
```

somewhere before server-start in their .emacs, and use "~/.emacs.d/server-dir/server" as the server socket name for the above mentioned alias. server-dir will be automatically created, with the right permissions 0700, if it does not already exist.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily the answer you are looking for, but I have in exactly the same setup always used just emacsclient -c or emacsclient -t. Meaning I don't start the server manually, the first invoking of either will start the server and any subsequent invoking will connect to the server.

Comment: This works for me, but again, within each specific terminal. So, if I start a new terminal, it will start a new server.

Comment: Do you have any server specific stuff in your .emacs? If so, I'd comment it out and try again. Otherwise I am out of ideas.

Comment: Also: which version of Emacs you are running? My setup works with both Emacs25 (25.1) from the Ubuntu depo and self-compiled Emacs25.2.

Comment: I don't think I have anything in the init file. I am running 25.3, but the same happened with 25.2. Also, launching the server with emacs -q --daemon does the same thing.

Comment: Out of ideas, sorry. Works in my setup, even with emacs -q --daemon.

Answer (score -2):

Create a script say "myemacs" as below:

```
#!/bin/bash
emacsclient -a '' -c "$@"
```

Run it will create daemon if not exist, and will connect to daemon if daemon exist.

Comment: This does not work. I get the same problem, If I launch it from two different terminals it creates a new daemon each time.

Comment: @MatíasGuzmánNaranjo Oh, but I saw you are using "-t", I am using "-c". Did you try "-c" also?

Comment: that doesn't change anything, it's the same behavior with either -c or -t. The client just can't find the server.

Comment: this does not work

Comment: I can confirm this does not work. The problem stems from the fact that --server-name is not set and `-a ''` is present. In recent versions of emacsclient this means starting a new emacs in daemon mode.